# How to disable antialiasing with styleSheet for Qt QWidget border

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I have a Qt QWidget with a border set up like so:

```
setStyleSheet( QString( "QWidget { border: 3px solid white; border-radius: 16px;}") );
```

The border has an antialiasing effect which looks like there is a fuzzy edge with an interpolation between the border color and the application background color. How can I disable antialiasing to have sharp edges?